# If two differential values are multiplied, can the product be left ignored due to its small size?

Tags: calculus, approximations

We can leave square of $dt$ ($t$ is time) ignored. But I am confused whether what's a "small" change for quantity $A$ can always or not be regarded as "small" compared to the small change in quantity $B$. For example, if we multiply $dN\,dt$ where $N$ is number of particles in a container and $t$ is time, $10^2$ is small enough for $dN$ (compared to $10^{23}$) but not at all small considering $dt$ takes values like 0.05. So can the product still be ignored from equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't ignore a member of your equation using sub members as reference.

Let's take the famous example of wanting to find how the area of a rectangle is influenced by the variation of one of its sides.

Let's say the sides are $x$ and $y$, the infinitesimal increment in area due to an infinitesimal increment of both sides will be:
\begin{align}
  dA &= (x+dx)(y+dy) - xy = x y + x dy + y dx + dx dy - xy
\\
     &= x dy + y dx + dx dy 
\end{align}
You can ignore the term $dx\,dy$ because is of a higher order than the other two, you have always to compare the member to an other member of the equation when you're trying to decide if it can be neglected.

I hope I understand your question correctly, maybe if you post your entire equation I can better understand what you wish to solve.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tricky situations you can get into, so let's think about an example. Consider a square prism with a square base of side length $x$ and height $h$. Then the volume is given by $V=x^2h$. Now let's consider what happens when the side length $x$ changes to $(1+\epsilon_x)x$, and let's say the height changes to $(1+\epsilon_h)h$. Then you can check that the volume changes to $\left(1+2\epsilon_x + \epsilon_x^2 + \epsilon_h + 2\epsilon_x \epsilon_h + \epsilon_x^2 \epsilon_h\right)V$.

Now given that $\epsilon_x\ll 1$ and $\epsilon_h\ll 1$, it is instructive to see what relationship be determined between the six terms in the parentheses. By using concepts you are familiar with from situations with a single variable, we already know that $  \epsilon_x^2 \ll 2 \epsilon_x \ll 1$ and $\epsilon_h\ll 1$. Are there any further relationships that can be deduced? Yes. By multiplying the first series of inequalities by $\epsilon_h$, we can find $  \epsilon_x^2\epsilon_h \ll 2 \epsilon_x\epsilon_h \ll \epsilon_h$. By multiplying $\epsilon_h\ll 1$ by $\epsilon_x^2$ we find $\epsilon_x^2 \epsilon_h\ll \epsilon_x^2$.

I think this is all that we can say in general. In particular there are two things that we can't say. We can't say that the $2\epsilon_x$ term is as significant as the $\epsilon_h$ term, even though they have the same power. It might be the case that $2\epsilon_x=.1$ and $\epsilon_h=0.00001$, or the situation might be the reverse. So we can't really compare these two terms. In fact, we can't even say that the $\epsilon_x^2$ is smaller than the $\epsilon_h$ term, even though the former has a higher power (this is the second thing we can't say). Imagine $\epsilon_x=0.1$ and $\epsilon_h=0.00001$. Then we actually have $\epsilon_h \ll \epsilon_x^2$.

The general rule is that the only inequalities you can be sure of are of the form $\left(\epsilon_x^m \epsilon_h^n\right) \epsilon_x^a \epsilon_h^b \ll \left(\epsilon_x^m \epsilon_h^n\right)$.